# Fabric always shows app update is available

Tags: android, macos, twitter-fabric

I have been using fabric since long time now. But since first I have started using I have been facing a issue and till the date have tried to search many times but never got any solution.

I use Mac to build android apps and when I send that apps on fabric for testing to clients it always shows update is available even if I downloaded latest version just now and than check again and it shows app update is available. And this only happens when I build apps from my mac when another person build same app, same source from windows than it works fine like after I download latest version it do not show version is available.

Any help on this ?

Comment: Maybe the version on their site is not the latest one... Did you try to update it via its UI when it asks?

Comment: yes, and I even tried installing beta app on my phone and check and it's same, it always shows update is available

Comment: Could you show screenshot?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/s2gve1hyhx3r6ak/device-2016-09-20-112958.png?dl=0

grayed out names sorry as it;s client's apps. But you see download symbol, never get removes if I send apk from mac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, Finally found solution, Basically it works fine if we just build the APK using Build command or option from menu and then send via fabric, it do not work if we send APK which was generated from Build and run.